# element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index in angularjs

Tags: typescript, angular11

***Elements implicitly has 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to indextype '{}'
No index signature with a parameter type 'string' was find on type '{}'

And also
showing object is possibly undefined.

---

**I tried to implement this code in a typescript file but it is showing these error.  Why? I am not able to find the error. please help.**

```
getGlobalData() {
    return this.http.get(this.globalDataUrl, { responseType: 'text' }).pipe(
      map(result => {
        let data: GlobalDataSummary[] = [];
        let raw = {}
        let rows = result.split('\n');
        rows.splice(0, 1);
        // console.log(rows);
        rows.forEach(row => {
          let cols = row.split(/,(?=\S)/)

          let cs = {
            country: cols[3],
            confirmed: +cols[7],
            deaths: +cols[8],
            recovered: +cols[9],
            active: +cols[10],
          };
          let temp: GlobalDataSummary = raw[cs.country];
          if (temp) {
            temp.active = cs.active + temp.active
            temp.confirmed = cs.confirmed + temp.confirmed
            temp.deaths = cs.deaths + temp.deaths
            temp.recovered = cs.recovered + temp.recovered

            raw[cs.country] = temp;
          } else {
            raw[cs.country] = cs;
          }
        })
        return <GlobalDataSummary[]>Object.values(raw);
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: If you just want the error to go away, `let raw:any = {}`. But doing this takes away the point of Typescript. You could even create an index type of `{ [string]:any}`. But even then your losing the benefits of Typings,  but I do this often as a temporary solution when refactoring existing code, to later create a better type.

Answer (score 0):

> expression of type 'string' can't be used to indextype '{}'

That means you cannot do `{}['somePropertyName']`. And that is because your `raw` variable has no explicit type and your code initialised it as `{}`, an empty object, which has no property indexer.

You can give `raw` a type that allows your code to get its property via a string index like so:

```
let raw: {
    [key: string]: any
};
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Error gone... But.... Now it is showing in temp : GlobalDataSummary that "object is possibly undefined" and in return <GlobalDataSummary [] >object. values (raw) that "variable raw is used before being assigned".... What should I do?